# Kang Ying Liu's work upon nine new geometric formulas for describing triangle inequalities

Tags: geometry, reference-request

Stack Exchangers, I was reading about Kang Ying Liu's work on discovering nine new geometric formulas for describing triangle inequalities.

> Kang Ying Liu of St. Andrew's Priory won the top prize at the 53rd Hawai'i State Science and Engineering Fair held April 6 and 7 at the Hawai'i Convention Center. Liu will join 21 other exceedingly bright Hawai'i students at the Intel International Science and Engineering Fair in San Jose, Calif. Liu won the competition by discovering nine new geometric formulas for describing triangle inequalities. One of the judges at the Hawai'i event, University of Hawai'i math professor J.B. Nation, said he had not seen such an accomplished display of abstract math at the fair in more than 30 years.

But I couldn't manage any pdf or document or on arxiv.org that contains her high-school work as mentioned above.
If anyone reading this topic, has a document of the same, please be kind enough to provide me a link.

Thanks and Regards,

mathbg.

Comment: Please provide the name of the pdf or other reference materials to narrow the search.

Comment: @Mick I had provided all the relevant details I could find to help people narrow down the search for me.

Comment: Hello, I'm just bumping the topic since it remains unanswered.